# Classification of plane angle as fundamental or derived

Tags: units, si-units, unit-conversion

I recently started with my high school studies and the chapter I am stuck at is **units and measurements.**

I was told about two types of physical quantities and my teacher gave me the following explanations:

**Fundamental Physical Quantities:**

Physical quantities that are independent of each other and cannot be broken down into smaller physical quantities are Fundamental.

**Derived Physical Quantities:**

Physical quantities that can be expressed by simply multiplying or dividing fundamental physical quantities are Derived.

Then while studying about **radians**, our teacher told us **that radian is the unit of derived physical quantity plane angle.**

When I asked him to express it as a equation of fundamental physical quantities he was not able to do it.

So my question is.. Is plane angle a fundamental physical quantity or is it derived and if it is derived why cannot it be expressed as fundamental quantities or is it some other problem that I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you take a circle of radius $\ell$ and take an arc of length $\ell$ along the circumference, then 1 radian is the angle subtended by the arc:

[image: Radian]

More generally, if the length of the arc is $\ell$ and the radius of the circle is $r$ then the angle in radians subtended by the arc is $\ell/r$.

So the radian is a derived unit because it is the ratio of two lengths.

Comment: Can we call the angle a "physical quantity"even if it has no dimensions ?

Answer (score 0):

Plane angle is indeed an independent physical quantity--and has been conceptualised as such for millennia, as summarised in Euclid's "Elements" in the third century BCE.  The "well-known" relationship between a circular arc and the circle's radius and corresponding central angle:

arc-length = (radius)x("angle in radians")

is confusing because of the misleading interpretation of "angle in radians" as an "angle" expressed in radians: (numerical value) rad. For dimensional consistency,  "angle in radians" must have the dimension of length/length = "1"--i.e. the "angle" appears to be dimensionless. This does NOT mean that a radian is a (dimensionless) derived unit--[the SI defines it as the derived unit m/m (= 1)].

What "angle in radians" really means is the numerical value of the (independent physical quantity) ANGLE when the angle is expressed in radians.  Thus, if theta is a central angle (with independent dimension A), the numerical value of theta (when theta is expressed in radians) is theta/rad--or the number of radians in theta.

The above relationship between arc-length, radius and central angle theta then becomes:

arc-length = (radius)x(theta/rad)

When rearranged explicitly for theta:

theta = (arc-length)/(radius) rad

we see that theta and rad both have the (independent) dimension A. And the equation is dimensionally consistent: A = (L/L)A = A. [The SI interpretation of "radian" is "the numerical value of one radian when the radian is expressed in radians"--or "the number of radians in one radian."  Clearly, this is identically equal to 1.]

BP Leonard

Emeritus Professor of Mechanical Engineering

The University of Akron

Comment: Hi and welcome to Phys.SE! Please use [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to write math equations.