# Why does the angular speed formula end up in radians per second?

Tags: units, rotation, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

So, in my homework I am given the radius and also the tangential speed $v$, the measurement for radius is meters; the measurement for $v$ is $m/s$. I don't understand how by after calculating the RPM it just ends up in radians?

Comment: [This question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/248676/) may help you, radian is the ratio of two lengths.

Comment: Well, I just don't get the concept of it having to do with two lengths...Because for example if I want to find the tangential speed at a specific time lets say t= .191 (homework problem); and my initial angular speed is .240 rev/s and radius is in meters. Whenever I throw this into the formula w = v/r, I then have to convert this into radians if I want to find it in radians...But this is the ratio of two lengths also, so why isn't this assumed to go to radian?

Comment: can u show us your calculation?

Comment: clarify your question please.  someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you confused about how you get into this?

$$\begin{align} v & = \omega\,r \\
({\rm m/s}) & = ({\rm rad/s})\,({\rm m}) = ({\rm m\,rad/s})
\end{align} $$

Radians are not units with dimensions. They can be seen as $({\rm rad}) = ({\rm m/m})$ like arc length to radius. This makes to above right hand side equivalent to the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is why

$$\omega(v, r) := \frac{v}{r}$$

where $v$ is the tangential speed, comes out in radians, and not some other unit like RPM, when there are no "obvious" unit factors around.

The reason for this is **geometry**, in particular it has to do with what a radian *is*. By definition, one radian is the angle required so that the length of the circular arc it sweeps out equals the circle's radius. That is, if we have the angle $\theta := 1\ \mathrm{rad}$, and $R$ is the circle's radius, and $s(\theta)$ is the length of the swept arc, we have

$$s(\theta) = R$$

at this angle.

Why can you do that? Well, proving this is a rather interesting mathematical exercise that touches on a fair bit of fundamentals of geometry. It is a bit difficult to do constructively, but can be considered as basically showing that the arc length of a circle's circumference is longer than its radius, which is possible with methods most famously employed by Archimedes: draw a regular polygon within the circle, centered at the center, and having one vertex on the circle's circumference. Since the polygon lies entirely inside, the circle must be longer. Yet we can now easily find the length of the polygon as its sides are straight lines - e.g. try a square! - and see its perimeter longer than the radius which is now a half-diagonal given how we constructed it.

Then the intermediate value theorem tells you that there must be a division of the circumference such that the length exactly equals its radius.

(It should also be pointed out that using regular polygons inscribed inside the circle, together with taking their *limit* as the number of sides becomes infinite, tells you how to *define* the arc length. In fact, the methods involved here could be considered the precursor to the calculus.)

Answer (score -1):

This is all true because the ratio of a circle's diameter to circumference is constant (pi). The unit of radian is actually chosen so that l = r.theta. So if you go theta radians around a circle you travel r.theta. For the angular to linear velocities, think of a disc rotating at an angular speed omaga. then the further out from the centre of the disc you are the fast you travelling... in fact you are travelling r.omaga m/s *if* you measure your angular velocity in radians/s.